React Google Maps API filtering markers leads to infinite loops
I am using this library: @vis.gl/react-google-maps. I have seen the following video which implements a map with clustering markers.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PfZ4oLftItk
therefore I implemented the following components:
import { APIProvider, Map } from "@vis.gl/react-google-maps";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useGetAppContext } from "../associated-garages/hooks/use-get-app-context";
import { appType, googleMapsApiKey, googleMapsIcons, googleMapsVariables } from "./GoogleMapUtilities";
import CustomMarkers from "./CustomMarkers";

function CustomMap({ typeOfApp }) {
  const [centerLatLng, setCenterLatLng] = useState(googleMapsVariables.CENTER);
  const [hoveredMarker, setHoveredMarker] = useState(null);

  const {
    state: { currentResults, selectedMarker },
    garageDispatch,
  } = useGetAppContext(appType.GARAGES);
   return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}>
     <APIProvider apiKey={googleMapsApiKey.DEV}>
       <Map
         mapId="DEMO_MAP_ID"
         defaultCenter={googleMapsVariables.CENTER}
         defaultZoom={googleMapsVariables.ZOOM}
       >
        <CustomMarkers points={currentResults} typeOfApp={typeOfApp} />
       </Map>
     </APIProvider>
   </div>
   );
  }

  CustomMap.propTypes = {
    typeOfApp: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  export default CustomMap;

and the CustomMarkers component:
import { MarkerClusterer } from "@googlemaps/markerclusterer";
import { AdvancedMarker, useMap } from "@vis.gl/react-google-maps";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useGetAppContext } from "../associated-garages/hooks/use-get-app-context";
import { GarageActionTypes, garageTypeCode, motorTypeCode } from "../associated-garages/utilities/TextUtilities";
import { appType, googleMapsIcons } from "./GoogleMapUtilities";
import markerShape from "./common/propTypes";

const CustomMarkers = ({ points, typeOfApp }) => {
  const map = useMap();
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState({});
  const clusterer = useRef(null);
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

  const {
    state: { selectedMarker },
    garageDispatch,
  } = useGetAppContext(appType.GARAGES);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;
    if (!clusterer.current) {
      clusterer.current = new MarkerClusterer({ map });
    }
  }, [map]);

  useEffect(() => {
    clusterer.current?.clearMarkers();
    clusterer.current?.addMarkers(Object.values(markers));
  }, [markers]);

  const setMarkerRef = (marker, key) => {
    if (marker && markers[key]) return;
    if (!marker && !markers[key]) return;

    setMarkers((prev) => {
      if (marker) {
        return { ...prev, [key]: marker };
      } else {
        const newMarkers = { ...prev };
        delete newMarkers[key];
        return newMarkers;
      }
    });
  };
return (
<React.Fragment>
  {points.map((point) => (
    <React.Fragment key={point.garageNo + "Fragment"}>
      <AdvancedMarker
        position={markerPosition(point)}
        title={markerTitle(point)}
        key={point.garageNo}
        onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(point)}
        ref={(marker) => setMarkerRef(marker, point.garageNo)}
      >
        <img src={markerIcon(point)} />
      </AdvancedMarker>
    </React.Fragment>
  ))}
</React.Fragment>


);
};

CustomMarkers.propTypes = {
  points: markerShape.marker,
  typeOfApp: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default CustomMarkers;

but when currentResults, which are passed as a prop, change as we filter them it causes the following error:
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

For the error that you are getting, could you please check this if it can help your problem?
